# Naming a dynamic cell range based on another worksheet.

Tags: dynamic, reference, range, named

I want to set up a dynamic cell range, which varies length and start point of the range based on user inputs.

I've named a range using the following formula:

=OFFSET(INDIRECT("P"&'FTB data (ML2)'!$N$420),0,0,'FTB data (ML2)'!$N$422,1)

Where:

FTB data (ML2) is the worksheet with the source of data

P is the start column of the data

N420 contains an input for the start row of the range

N422 contains the input for the length of the range

Now this all seems to more or less work, the length varies according to the value in N422 and the start varies based on N420.

The problem is that it's not fixed to the FTB data (ML2) worksheet. I.e when I change tabs to my Summary Sheet, it draws from the range in the summary sheet, no tthe FTB data sheet.

Does anybody have any idea how to make sure it only draws from FTB data, and not the currently active sheet?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working with the following formula:

=OFFSET(INDIRECT("'" & "FTB Data (ML2)" & "'!" & "P"&Summary!$C$1),0,0,'FTB data (ML2)'!$N$422,1)

Turns out you just need a few more ' and " floating about to get an INDIRECT to reference another worksheet correctly.